# Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac {\cos(\theta)}{5-3\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta$ using residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am to evaluate the following integral using residue theorem:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac {\cos(\theta)}{5-3\cos(\theta)} \, d\theta$$

I know that I need to perform substitution with the following:

$$d\theta = \frac {dz}{iz}$$

$$\cos\theta = \frac 12(z+\frac1z)$$

which yields:
$$\frac 1i=\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z+\frac1z}{-3z^2+10z-3}\, dz$$

Finding the roots for the denominator yields two roots at $1/3$ and $3.$ Only $1/3$ falls within our unit circle so we ignore the root at $3.$

This is where I am a little stuck. I was taught to use the shortcut here to calculate the residue where I would leave the numerator $p(z)$ as is and take the derivative of the denominator $q'(z)$ then plug in the value of the singularity $z=\frac13$ but this approach doesn't give me the correct answer which I know is $\frac\pi6$

Am I making a mistake in setting up the problem? Thanks!

Comment: $z+\frac{1}{z}$ has a singularity at $z=0$, too.

Comment: By exploiting the symmetry of the cosine function you may also write the original integral as $$ 12\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{25-9\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta $$ which becomes an elementary integral after the substitution $\theta=\arctan t$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(\theta)}{5-3\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\frac12(z+z^{-1})}{5-\frac32(z+z^{-1})}\frac1{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2+1}{z(3z^2-10z+3)}\,dz\\\\
&=i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2+1}{z(3z-1)(z-3)}\,dz\\\\
&=-2\pi \text{Res}\left(\frac{z^2+1}{z(3z-1)(z-3)}, z=0,1/3\right)\\\\
&=-2\pi \left(\frac13-\frac5{12}\right)\\\\
&=\frac\pi6
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! Quick question, why did you bring out the $\frac1i$ from the first line as $i$ in front of the integral instead of $\frac1i$?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that $\frac1i =-i$.